# Adding @Size annotation conditionally if variable is set to specific value in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Java Spring Boot application, and I have a class called "CustomClass". Here is the class definition:

```java
public class CustomClass {
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String name;

    private String type;
}
```

Right now, I have the size of the `name` variable set to be a minimum of 3 characters in length. Some logic changed, and I only want that `@Size(min = 3)` annotation to be applied to the `name` field only if the `type` is a specific value, let's say `Type 1`. So it might look like this:

```java
if (type == "Type 1") @Size(min = 3)
private String name;
```

Is this possible, or do I need to create a separate class to handle these different constraints?

Comment: I think your only option is custom annotation on the class level. As far as i know, it's not possible to access the value of one field from another field's annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate method for this logic validation, for example like this:

```
public class CustomClass {
    private String name;

    private String type;

    @JsonIgnore
    @AssertTrue(message = "name must be at least 3 characters long if type is Type 1")
    public boolean isNameValid() {
        if ("Type 1".equals(type)) {
            return name != null && name.length() >= 3;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Validation mechanism will check this for you.

Comment: What validation mechanism are you suggesting? The nice part about using `@Size` is that it automatically validates the input as the class is constructed. With `isNameValid` method, where would I call this?

Comment: @Michael `@AssertTrue` annotation is also a part of `javax.validation.constraints`, so you don't need to call this method - it will be called for you automatically by the same mechanism, which runs validation on fields with `@Size` annotation.

Comment: @Michael this annotation works on boolean fields and on methods which start with "is" (like a getter method), and you can also provide your custom message there as you do in any other validation annotations